# Input/label position manipulation without CSS frameworks, only with CSS3

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to manipulate the position of inputs and labels I almost tried everything I know and can't achieve the desired form. I have this code of HTML

```css
.section-three-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: url("images/footer/Intersection\ 1.png") center/cover no-repeat;
  ;
  height: 80vh;
}

.wrapper-form {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 55px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-three-container">
  <!-- <h2 class="wrapper header-edit">Section Three</h2> -->
  <form action="" class="wrapper-form">

    <h3>CONTACT US</h3>
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" />

    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />

    <label for="message">Your message</label>
    <textarea id="textbox" name="message"></textarea>

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" />

    <label for="number">Phone Number</label>
    <input type="number" id="fnumber" name="fnumber" />

    <button class="btn-send">SEND</button>

  </form>
</div>
```

And this is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Thank you guys for the help, you all gave me a good answer with different perspective on how to solve the problem. I was just checking them all out and will try all of them and see which one suits the best, thanks again! Btw I was trying also to put them in different two divs but coudn't manage to position them correctly.

Comment: Also, @Alimur, why am I getting negative marks on asking questions? Are they badly asked or what is the reason? I mean I do everything to clarify the question what else should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.form-fields {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.input-field {
  width: 50%;
}

.input-field input,
.input-field textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-three-container">
  <!-- <h2 class="wrapper header-edit">Section Three</h2> -->
  <form action="" class="wrapper-form">

    <h3>CONTACT US</h3>

    <div class="form-fields">
      <div class="input-field">
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" />
      </div>

      <div class="input-field">
        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
      </div>

      <div class="input-field">
        <label for="message">Your message</label>
        <textarea id="textbox" name="message"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="input-field">
        <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" />
      </div>

      <div class="input-field">
        <label for="number">Phone Number</label>
        <input type="number" id="fnumber" name="fnumber" />
      </div>

      <div class="input-field">
        <button class="btn-send">SEND</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

I've grouped your inputs and labels into divs. These divs has `width: 50%` and parent container has `display: flex`, so there are 2 such divs at row

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

1. Group every two inputs in a div so that they are in same row.
   `flex-direction: row;` place them in same row. justify-content: space-between;
   confirms space between the inputs.
2. place label and inputs in a div, they are in same column.
   `flex-direction: column;` line added to place them in same column.

   ```
   <div class="section-three-container">
     <form action="" class="wrapper-form">
      <h3>CONTACT US</h3>
      <div class="flex-row mt-20">
      <div class="flex-column">
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" /> 
     </div>
     <div class="flex-column">
        <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" />
     </div>
    </div>
       <div class="flex-row mt-20">
     <div class="flex-column">
        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
     </div>
     <div class="flex-column">
        <label for="number">Phone Number</label>
        <input type="number" id="fnumber" name="fnumber" />
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row mt-20">
     <div class="flex-column">
        <label for="message">Your message</label>
        <textarea id="textbox" name="message"></textarea>
     </div>
       <div class="flex-column flex-column-end">
        <button class="btn-send">SEND</button>
       </div>
    </div>
   </form>
   </div>


   .flex-row {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
   .flex-column {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
   .ml-20 {
      margin-left: 20px;
   }
   .mt-20 {
      margin-top: 20px;
   }
   .flex-column-end {
      justify-content: flex-end;
   }
   ```

working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/8prh4ecz/

Answer (score 0):

Use a grid layout. Define the grid-template-rows/columns as fractional increments whose children will take up that amount of the percentage of 100% width/height of their parents.

So a layout with two columns where the inputs basically are in two columns, ***first name in one and last name in the other***, we have `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr`, this means that the parents width will be distributed within those two columns equally 1 fraction each (*2 columns*). This basically is the same rule with the rows.

Then in the `grid-template-areas:` you literally display the selector of the children in the layout you want them to take up.

Check out the breakdown here:

```css
    grid-template-areas: 
        "heading      heading"      //<-- row 1
        "first-name   last-name"    //<-- row 2
        "email        phone"        //<-- row 3
        "message      button";      //<-- row 4
     //  ^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^
     //  col one      col two
```

This matches in a literal sense the layout of our HTML (***with css***) within the grid parent element.

Lastly, each child will have `grid-area:` where it calls on its own selector. ie:

```css
.first-name {
  grid-area: first-name;
}
```

From there it's all about styling your other elements accordingly. I used a few utility styles like `flex-col` and `flex-end`, to add specific flex styling to the children divs for alignment and spacing etc...

```css
.section-three-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: url("https://www.hdnicewallpapers.com/Walls/Big/Nature%20and%20Landscape/Beautiful_Sunrising_Nature_Image.jpg") center/cover no-repeat;
  height: 80vh;
  min-height: 300px;
  width: 80vw;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper-form {
  width: 98%;
  height: 98%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "heading heading" 
    "first-name last-name" 
    "email phone" 
    "message button";
}

.flex-end {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
  align-items: end;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.flex-col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: space-between;
}

.flex-col input, .flex-col textarea {
  border-radius: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

.btn-send {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: .5rem 2.5rem;
}

.box {
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

.heading {
  grid-area: heading;
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

.first-name {
  grid-area: first-name;
}

.last-name {
  grid-area: last-name;
}

.email {
  grid-area: email;
}

.phone {
  grid-area: phone;
}

.message {
  grid-area: message;
}

.button {
  grid-area: button;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-three-container">
  <!-- <h2 class="wrapper header-edit">Section Three</h2> -->
  <form action="" class="wrapper-form">

    <!--/added div wrapper around each "section" with 
         a unique selector for use in grid css /-->
    <div class="heading">
      <h3>CONTACT US</h3>
    </div>
    <!--/added div wrapper around each "section" with 
         a unique selector for use in grid css /-->    
    <div class="first-name flex-col box">
      <label for="fname">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" />
    </div>    
    <!--/added div wrapper around each "section" with 
         a unique selector for use in grid css /-->    
    <div class="last-name flex-col box">
      <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" />
    </div>
    <!--/added div wrapper around each "section" with 
         a unique selector for use in grid css /-->    
    <div class="email flex-col box">
      <label for="email">Email Address</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
    </div>
    <!--/added div wrapper around each "section" with 
         a unique selector for use in grid css /-->
    <div class="phone flex-col box">
      <label for="fnumber">Phone Number</label>
      <input type="text" id="fnumber" name="fnumber" />
    </div>    
    <!--/added div wrapper around each "section" with 
         a unique selector for use in grid css /-->
    <div class="message flex-col box">
      <label for="message">Your message</label>
      <textarea id="textbox" name="message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <!--/added div wrapper around each "section" with 
         a unique selector for use in grid css /-->    
    <div class="button flex-end box">
      <button class="btn-send">SEND</button>
    </div>














  </form>
</div>
```